# Passing unexpected parameters to a callback function

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there is a way to pass an additional parameter to a callback function besides what the parent function passes it

```
function wrapper() {
    function functionForPassing() {
        console.log('carrot');
    }

    function test(a, b, cb) {
        cb(a,b);
    }

    test('apple', 'banana', function(first, second, passedFunction=functionForPassing) {
        console.log(first);
        console.log(second);
        passedFunction();
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, what you have works, doesn't it? (although unnecessary because you could directly access `functionForPassing`). Why/where/how do you want to pass another parameter?

Comment: JS doesn't support default params like c#.

Comment: As Felix Kling is saying, it depends on what you want to pass the additional parameter from. Think about this in the context of usage. Using `wrapper()`, what do you want to happen?

Comment: @Daniel that's not true. JavaScript supports default parameters, but it does not support _named_ parameters.

Comment: I'd go with a higher order function to first inject the "config" and return a function that takes the data/arguments from `test()`. Like that `var foo = (passedFunction) => (first, second) => { console.log(first, second); passedFunction() };` and then `test("apple", "banana", foo(functionForPassing)); You can also check out the topic of *partially applied functions*, in JS often called *currying*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using rest parameter, but callback must go first.
Example:

```
function wrapper() {
    function functionForPassing() {
        console.log('carrot');
    }

    function test(cb, ...params) {
        cb(...params);
    }

    test(function(...other) {
        let [first, second] = other; // Destructuring assignment
        console.log(first);
        console.log(second);
    }, 'apple', 'banana', 'any', 'number', 'of', 'arguments');
}
```

Comment: ...what? attempting to evaluate `console.log(first)` would throw a `ReferenceError`

Comment: rest params would require a shim. They are not widely supported. http://caniuse.com/#feat=rest-parameters

Comment: @Daniel if default parameters are supported, then so would rest params.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wrapper() {
    function functionForPassing() {
        console.log('carrot');
    }

    function test(a, b, cb) {
        cb(a, b);
    }

    test('apple', 'banana', function(first, second, passedFunction) {
        passedFunction = passedFunction || functionForPassing;
        console.log(first);
        console.log(second);
        passedFunction();
    });
}

wrapper();
```

Answer (score 0):

The tiered scoping of js handles this for me, without having to pass the the object I am trying to access as a parameter to the callback

```
function wrapper() {
    var other = "carrot"

    function test(a, b, cb) {
        cb(a,b);
    }

    test('apple', 'banana', function(first, second) {
        console.log(first);
        console.log(second);
        console.log(other);
    });
}
wrapper();
```